# consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@localhost:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, airflow

I am trying to build my airflow using docker and rabbitMQ. I am using rabbitmq:3-management image. And I am able to access rabbitMQ UI, and API.

In airflow I am building airflow webserver, airflow scheduler, airflow worker and airflow flower. Airflow.cfg file is used to config airflow.

Where I am using `broker_url = amqp://user:password@127.0.0.1:5672/` and  `celery_result_backend = amqp://user:password@127.0.0.1:5672/`

My docker compose file is as follows

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbit1:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbit1"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "user"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

    labels:
      NAME: "rabbitmq1"

  webserver:
    build: "airflow/"
    hostname: "webserver"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EXECUTOR=Celery
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - rabbit1
    command:  webserver

  scheduler:
    build: "airflow/"
    hostname: "scheduler"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EXECUTOR=Celery
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - flower
      - worker
    command: scheduler

  worker:
    build: "airflow/"
    hostname: "worker"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    environment:
      - EXECUTOR=Celery
    command: worker

  flower:
    build: "airflow/"
    hostname: "flower"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EXECUTOR=Celery
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - rabbit1
      - webserver
      - worker
    command: flower
```

I am able to build images using docker compose. However, I am not able to connect my airflow scheduler to rabbitMQ. I am getting following error:

> consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@localhost:5672//: [Errno
>   111] Connection refused.

I have tried using 127.0.0.1 and localhost both.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From within your `airflow` containers, you should be able to connect to the service `rabbit1`. So all you need to do is to change `amqp://user:**@localhost:5672//:` to `amqp://user:**@rabbit1:5672//:` and it should work.

Docker compose creates a default network and attaches services that do not explicitly define a network to it.

You do not need to expose the 5672 & 15672 ports on rabbit1 unless you want to be able to access it from outside the application.

Also, generally it is not recommended to build images inside docker-compose.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this issue by installing rabbitMQ server into my system with command `sudo apt install rabbitmq-server`.

Comment: My django project was using rabbitMQ, helped!

Comment: Tip: This works especially if you aren't using docker