# django settings does not affect after changes(CELERY_BROKER_URL)

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'
```

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

```
[2022-02-14 12:02:26,910: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@192.168.3.100%3A6379:5672//: failed to resolve broker hostname.
```

Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:\*\*@localhost:5672//: \[Errno 111\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710248/consumer-cannot-connect-to-amqp-userlocalhost5672-errno-111-connect)

Comment: please show the code where you instantiate celery app. It seems that the dango settings are not taken into account at all.